# executing a function after submiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, highcharts

I am not able to call jQuery on submit. The  $('#container').highcharts({}) in the function is not displayed .
My object is  to display a line charte after the submit of the form. But the function called in the script didn't executed .

here's my code:

```
         <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 

    <html>
     <head>
       <title> </title>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <form Action="Home/Index" method="post"  id="roleManagement" >

            <span><b> Choisir le taux de change  </b> </span><br />
            <div id="checkboxes">
             <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="taux" value="EUR/USD" checked="checked" >EUR/USD<br>
             <br>
            </div>
           <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date de début</th>
                    <th>Date de fin</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="Date" name="date_début" id="date_début" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="Date" name="date_fin" id="date_fin"  />
                    </td>
                <\tr>
           </table>

            <br />
          <input type="submit" value="CHERCHER" name="affiche"  />
          <input type="reset" value="Reset">@Html.ActionLink("Réessayer", "Index")</button>
      </form>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#roleManagement").submit(function() {
           $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function () {
           $('#container').highcharts({
               title: {
                  text: 'Taux de change',
                   x: -20
                      },
              subtitle: {
                  text: 'taux de change',
                  x: -20
            },
              xAxis: {
                categories: [1, 3, 9]

                     },
              yAxis: {
                  title: {
                      text: 'Taux de change'
                         },
                 plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'EUR/USD',
                data: [4, 8, 9]

            }]

        });
        });
    });
    $.each(selected, function (key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    });
});
   </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you submit a form, the page is reloaded. Any script from the previous page stop.

Comment: Where do you expect the chart to be displayed, since submitting the form will replace the page with the results from `Home/Index`?

Comment: Barmer, I want the chart to be displayed in the same page of the forme.After the return from the controller , the chart will be displayed in the same page .I don't know where the problem is !!

Comment: Whe I wrote alert in the two first declaration of the function it executed .I guess that the priblem is start with this  $('#container').highcharts({}) and I don't know why !

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/up64zru7/ ?

Comment: If you want to display the chart without reloading, you need to disable form submission. Maybe you should be using AJAX?

Comment: Seems like you have the `<script>` tags of highcharts out of the `<head>` tag, try putting them after the `<script>` where you load jQuery